# Improving JEST testing performance with vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I have a simple app with few component and only one test for Login.vue component, calling jest takes from 20 to 10 seconds. Is there a way to improve the performance or everyone is getting same results.

### jest.conf.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/e2e'
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
}
```

### With coverage

[image: With coverage]

### Without coverage

[image: Without coverage]

### Edit

Adding [roots](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#roots-array-string) directories is seems to improve test for few seconds.

```
roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
    '<rootDir>/test'
  ],
```

> PASS  test/unit/specs/Login.spec.js (5.647s)
>
> Login.vue
>
> ```
> ✓ has login method (21ms)
> ```

Comment: how long does your app to load, in real time, without the test?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- less than a sec

Comment: if you have istanbul in your .babelrc try removing it? Maybe not a speed issue but it was causing me all kinds of issues with coverage testing

Comment: @reddiky no istanbul in .babelrc

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with jest taking too long.

The thing I did that had a big impact is to limit the test directory. Instead of scouring the src folder for test coverage, I've defined a folder where the unit tests are by defining the roots folder

```
"roots": [
  "<rootDir>/test/jest"
]
```

or

[src](https://github.com/jsdf/posts/blob/master/content/Make-Jest-tests-run-fast.md#limit-the-scope-of-jests-file-discovery)

```
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/tmp"
  ],
  "testPathDirs": [
    "<rootDir>/app/client",
    "<rootDir>/lib/client"
  ],
```

The other thing you can do is to use compiled versions of dependencies
[ref](https://github.com/jsdf/posts/blob/master/content/Make-Jest-tests-run-fast.md#use-compiled-versions-of-big-dependencies)

I haven't tested that one, but seems like that should help too

Comment: https://github.com/jsdf/posts/blob/master/content/Make-Jest-tests-run-fast.md#use-compiled-versions-of-big-dependencies very old post and its not working

Comment: I get the error `Cannot find module 'jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader'`

Comment: if you're using `roots` you can use the `modulePaths` option to define missing paths. Or you can use `modulePathIgnorePatterns` to blacklist modules, but that's probably more work.